# Laravel 5 - Redirigir a HTTPS

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Trabajando en mi primer proyecto de Laravel 5 no estoy seguro de dónde ni cómo plasmar la lógica para forzar una redirección al protocolo HTTPS en mi aplicación. El punto clave acá es que hay muchos dominios apuntando a mi aplicación y solo dos de tres usan SSL (el tercero recurre a otro dominio, es una larga historia). Entonces, me gustaría manejar esta situación en la lógica de aplicación en lugar de editar el archivo .htacces.

En Laravel 4.2 pude completar la redirección con este código, agregado en el archivo `filters.php`

```
App::before(function($request)
{
    if( ! Request::secure())
    {
        return Redirect::secure(Request::path());
    }
});
```

Estoy pensando que una clase Middleware donde creo que algo como lo anterior debería ser implementado, pero no logro figurar cómo.

---

Esta es una pregunta originalmente publicada por [@NightMICU](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28402726/1424329)

Comment: La persona que votó negativo al menos podría dejar algún comentario. Gracias.

Comment: ¿Por que no usar un re-direccionamiento por medio del .htaccess?

Comment: @Chofoteddy, porque si lo hace desde el .htaccess no se podría hacer distinción de ambiente de trabajo. Muchas veces queremos que la redirección solo se dé en producción y no en preproducción,  claro,  a menos que usted quiera tener un htaccess por cada ambiente o por cada servidor donde se clone.

Comment: Entiendo. De hecho para eso también hay solución por medio del **RewriteCond**, dónde con una regla de expresión regular puedes determinar cuando sí o no aplicar el re-direccionamiento.

Comment: Bueno,  eso lo determinará la persona que necesite la solución. Su solución es aplicable también.  Tenga también en cuenta que si el proyecto se clonará en diferentes servidores y diferentes dominios también se puede volver un poco caótico. Al final se opta por la que mejor se adecue

Answer (score 6):

Usted puede hacer funcionar la redirección efectivamente con una clase Middleware. Déjeme darle una idea:

```
namespace MyApp\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class ProtocoloHttps {

    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (!$request->secure() && env('APP_ENV') === 'prod') {
            return redirect()->secure($request->getRequestUri());
        }

        return $next($request); 
    }
}
```

Para aplicar esta clase en cada solicitud usted debe agregar la clase al archivo `Kernel.php` como se mira a continuación:

```
protected $middleware = [
    'Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode',
    'Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\EncryptCookies',
    'Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse',
    'Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession',
    'Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession',

    // Redirección de protocolo
    'MyApp\Http\Middleware\ProtocolHttps'       

];
```

Al agregar la clase al array de `$middleware` todas las solicitudes de su aplicación serán redirigidas a HTTPS si:

1. La petición actual viene del protocolo http normal.
2. Si el ambiente de su aplicación es igual a `prod` (ajuste este valor a sus preferencias).

---

La respuesta fue brindada por mi persona desde el enunciado original.

Answer (score 0):

Mira la forma mas fácil es que hagas la validación desde tu acción en el controlador, si no se cumple la condición pones:

```
return redirect('aqui la ruta a donde lo quieres llevar');
```

Para mi, esta es la solución mas simple.

Comment: Hola, técnicamente es una solución posible, ¿pero qué pasa si tiene 50 controladores? Tendría que editar todos los controladores. ¿Y si el servidor cambia de protocolo/url? Tendría que volver a editar todos los controladores nuevamente.